# Complex Order By Queries using Rails 3.0 + Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-order-by

Does rails have any way to have complex sorting at the database query level?

Ie/

`Posts.order(up / down).all` ?

What would be the best way to implement this on a database level (in postgres) without having to sort through a result in ruby using sort (which will slow down pagination etc).

Comment: look out for data where down = 0 of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the wonderful `meta_where` gem, you can also do something like

```
Post.order(:create_at.asc)
```

To sort by a function of two or more columns you can do something like

```
Post.select("*, (up / down) as ratio").order("ratio asc")
```

You will have what you want and moreover every `Post` object in that array will have a `ratio` method for you to know the exact value.

Comment: I'm looking for doing math on multiple order bys, not just one field.

Comment: What does that mean? Give an example, please.

Comment: Example is in the original post.

Post.order(up / down).all
order by up column divided by down column.

Comment: Perfect!!
I'm going to try this out again today - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.order("created_at DESC").all
Post.order("title ASC").all
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering), for more details.

Comment: I'm looking for doing math on multiple order bys, not just one field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.select("*, (up / greatest(down, 1)) as ratio").order("ratio asc")
```